# To Integrate Kafka Consumer And Producer in a single function

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-flink, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

We need to develop a code where a Consumer runs listening to a particular kafka producer and then in the same function produce a processed data from the current consumed one to a different producer topic.

This is to integrate, flinks code with Java, where Java produces a message to one topic and flink consumes it and produces a new data to a different topic for Java to further work on it.

Please let us know if there is another way to do this process.

Comment: here is one example of using Kafka with Spark, you can replace Spark to Flink in your use case. http://felipeogutierrez.blogspot.com.br/2018/01/use-case-to-count-words-with-spark-and.html

Answer (score 5):

[Flink integrates nicely with Kafka](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/connectors/kafka.html), and can take advantage of Kafka transactions if needed. Such an application would look something like this:

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
FlinkKafkaConsumer011<> consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer011<IN>(topic_in, serializer_in, kafkaProperties);
FlinkKafkaProducer011<> producer = new FlinkKafkaProducer011<OUT>(broker, topic_out, serializer_out)

env.addSource(consumer)
   .map(new SuitableTransformation())
   .addSink(producer)
   .execute()
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the "read-process-write" pattern. You can make use of Kafka's [transaction functionality](https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/) to make this process atomic (or not, it's up to you, but the example below uses transactions):

```
KafkaProducer producer = createKafkaProducer(
  "bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092",
  "transactional.id", "my-transactional-id");

producer.initTransactions();

KafkaConsumer consumer = createKafkaConsumer(
  "bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092",
  "group.id", "my-group-id",
  "isolation.level", "read_committed");

consumer.subscribe(singleton("inputTopic"));

while (true) {
  ConsumerRecords records = consumer.poll(Long.MAX_VALUE);
  producer.beginTransaction();
  for (ConsumerRecord record : records)
    producer.send(producerRecord("outputTopic", record));
  producer.sendOffsetsToTransaction(currentOffsets(consumer), group);  
  producer.commitTransaction();
}
```

> This is to integrate, flinks code with Java, where Java produces a message to one topic and flink consumes it and produces a new data to a different topic for Java to further work on it.

You may want to consider Kafka Streams: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/index.html

Answer (score 0):

This sound like good place to use [akka streams](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-kafka/current/consumer.html#connecting-producer-and-consumer),

```
    val done =
  Consumer.committableSource(consumerSettings, Subscriptions.topics("topic1"))
    .map(msg => ProducerMessage.Message(new ProducerRecord[Array[Byte], String]("topic2", msg.record.value), msg.committableOffset))
    .via(Producer.flow(producerSettings))
    .map(_.message.passThrough)
    .batch(max = 20, first => CommittableOffsetBatch.empty.updated(first)) { (batch, elem) =>
      batch.updated(elem)
    }
    .mapAsync(3)(_.commitScaladsl())
    .runWith(Sink.ignore)
```